# Database Security (phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I have put phmyadmin folder on our server root folder. I m accessing database like www.example.com/phpmyadmin. I want to access it through only my ip address no other can access my database. Can any one help me. Thanks

Comment: you can protect your phpmyadmin via http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: Thank u for ur valuable suggestion. Actually i want to do change on phpmyadmin folder is there way to change configuration of phpmadmin. so that only one ip address can access phpmadmin

Answer (score 0):

## set prevention in  'hosts.allow' and hosts.deny file

You can edit your hosts files and configure it as it will allow only specific ip only to access your server files or database. 
[Try, this may help.](http://its.virginia.edu/unixsys/sec/hosts.html)

Comment: Thank u for ur suggestion. Actually want to configure on phpmadmin folder. is there any way to change configuration of phpmyadmin. I have put phpmyadmin folder on server root directory